# Java HTTP PUT not sending the data

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, url

I want to send some data to a server over HTTP PUT (calling a REST web service). Below is the code..

```
URL urlObj = new URL("http://99.66.66.238:8443/media/service");
          HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        conn.setRequestProperty("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        writer.write(requestXML);
        conn.getOutputStream().flush();
```

But on the other side, they do not get the data. They only see..

```
PUT /media/service HTTP/1.1
accept-charset: UTF-8
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic cm10dGVzdDpwYXNzd29yZA=3D=3D
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_13
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=3D.2, */*; q=3D.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Notice how the Content-Length is 0. Can you please tell me why the data is not going through? Is there anyway I can see exactly what I am sending?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Content-Length and Content-type headers?  It may be the case that the server isn't bothering to read anything because the headers aren't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need too **flush** out all the **buffered** output. Maybe you only want to use:

```
conn.getOutputStream().write(requestXML.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

This flush the output automatically.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that worked. The other side got the output. Just one problem now is that the words "3D" seem to be appended to the XML's first line.. <?xml version=3D"1.0" encoding=3D"UTF-8"?>. Would you why know this is happening?

Comment: You can use the class `javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility`. eg. `ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8")); InputStream out = MimeUtility.decode(is, "quoted-printable");`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you call the flush() on the writer instead of the connection's output stream? Seems to me the data might still be in the writer's buffer when you flush the connection's output stream, which would explain the 0 bytes sent.